# Publish React app to Github Pages using github Actions

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages, github-actions

I made a simple Reactjs app and now I want to publish it on gh-pages.
I followed [this Facebook tutorial](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom) for deploying it and it is also getting deployed from my PC. But now instead of every time manually deploying it, I thought of using *Github Actions* to deploy on every **push to the master branch**. so I wrote the below Action.

```
name: gh pages publish

on:
  push:
    branches: master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    with:
      node-version: 12
      registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
  - name: publish package
    run: |
      yarn
      npm run deploy
```

But this action fails because it requires the user to input the username and password.

```
> gh-pages -d build
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! timetablemanager@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the timetablemanager@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2020-06-21T07_07_19_700Z-debug.log
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

**How can I fix this?**

Edit:
Here is the package.json file

```
    {
  "homepage": "http://itissandeep98.github.io/TimeTableManager/",
  "name": "timetablemanager",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you could provide your `package.json`, it would help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the create react app github pages troubleshoot [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#troubleshooting), you need to do the following.

1. Create a new [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens)
2. `git remote set-url origin https://<user>:<token>@github.com/<user>/<repo>`.
3. Try `npm run deploy` again

Also make sure everything in your package.json is correct, but this definitely looks like an authentication issue.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here for those looking to do the same as the OG:

I created and added a [personal token](https://github.com/settings/tokens), and also faced some more issues.

Here are the changes I ended up making on the action file:

```
      - name: setup git authentication 
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "<me>@<gmail>.com"
          git config --global user.name "<my_name>"
          git remote set-url origin https://<user>:<token>@github.com/<user>/<repo>

      - name: publish
        run: |
          yarn
          npm run deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who ends up here, you can use the `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` that is available [on every action](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow), without setting it directly in the settings for your repo.

use Joey Baruch's answer above, just replace `<token>` with:

```
${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

P.s. stackoverflow wont let me comment yet so I had to post this as a separate answer.